# multi-users database structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication, sign

hello I am making a web system with PHP but one of the requirements that there are multiple users in multiple tables
user_table, teacher_table , student_table
how can I when I sign up as a user and be asked to which category I belong and be added to the user_table and student table at the same time
maybe the requirements I got is wrong?
because I couldn't find any tutorial

Comment: Well, don't do that. Make one table with a classifier column. And then three views, if need be.

Comment: what do you mean by three views?

Comment: If you don't know what it is, you probably won't need it. `CREATE VIEW students AS SELECT * FROM users WHERE role='student';`

Comment: so you are saying that i won't need a more than one table and I should add a type column

Comment: @mario even when i have different columns for the students table and the teachers tables

Comment: The linked question touches on that. If your question was meant to be about an existing misdesign or concrete implementation woes, you will have to [edit] your question with more details (and preferrably some research / we have piles of similar questions).